# unable to set CONTEXTUAL FILTERS according to Raw Value from Url

Tags: nodes, views, blocks

In my project having two type of Content Type 1) Artist and 2) Work

I have added the content for the Artist and now also i have added  the content for the Work according to Artist Name having field name `(Artist field_artist    Entity reference)`

On view Page i want to show the result according to the artist

```
http://localhost/drupal8/artists-works/robert
```

According to name `robert` i have set the `CONTEXTUAL FILTERS` and `Relationship`.but its not showing any result 
when removed the filter its showing all the work content type type
How can I set CONTEXTUAL FILTERS and Relationship according to this [image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a relationship to the content, and use the title (or whatever field contains "robert") as the contextual filter instead.

Currently the query that's getting built is trying to find content with an ID of "robert", which won't work as `nid` is numeric.

Comment: i have set the Content referenced from field_artist its using in the work content type for relationship

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. You need to use the title from the field_artist relationship as the contextual filter

Comment: In work content type , i have the field for artist and  insert record according to that artist name : example "/artists" url its showing the details of all artists after click on the one of robert it redirect to this path  "/artists-works/robert" . Now i want to fetch all the work content type record according to this name "robert". Now its showing me all records of work content type ,

Comment: I can only reiterate what I said in the answer and previous comment -that's how to fix your problem